# SyncFusion Blazor AutoComplete does not accept space in input

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly, syncfusion, syncfusion-blazor

I bind an autocomplete to list where the data is retrieved by API, on entering values in the input it seems that it does not accept space. Every time I press space, it looks like the control is "searching" but the space is not accepted in the input, so I'm not able to write a search string with spaces like "space is not accepted".

```
    <SfAutoComplete ID="Maker" @bind-Value="@(Item.Maker)" TValue="string" TItem="MakerDto" Placeholder="Produsent" FloatLabelType="FloatLabelType.Always" DataSource="@Makers">
 
 <AutoCompleteFieldSettings Value="Name"></AutoCompleteFieldSettings>
    
    </SfAutoComplete>
```

[image]

Comment: Is there any logic in `Item.Maker`s getter/setter? What if spaces _are_ actually present but you have a CSS property set that collapses whitespace so it isn't visible (but actually there)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have already resolved the reported issue of "Unable to enter a space character in the input field of the dropdown components" in our 21.2.3 version. Therefore, we recommend that you upgrade your packages to the latest version to address the current issue.

Feedback:
https://www.syncfusion.com/feedback/43219

Regards,
Mohanraj M